# Break a text in a label in iphone

Tags: iphone, text, label

I am new to iphone development.I have created three labels  in a cell and i have just displayed the text in the corresponding labels , but i want to display the full text in the label.I am not able to see the full text,So is there any possibility for breaking the text and show them in two lines.I am not displaying any  static text .I am getting the text dynamically from the website and displaying it in the label.Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. set label's `numberOfLines` property to 2 (or to 0 to have any number of lines you need)
2. set label's `lineBreakMode` property (e.g. to `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`)
3. make sure that label's height is enough to contain 2 (or more) lines of text